# Regular Expression in MVC of c# to match characters

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using a regular expression to match some characters like `ç"·$%&/()=?`, etc.

I am testing the regular expression in the web page

```
http://www.softlion.com/webTools/RegExpTest/default.aspx
```

and it is working but when I use the regular expression in my model of MVC it is not working and always I display the message of error.

The instruction used in c# is:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[ç\"·$%&/()=?]$", ErrorMessage="some message")]
```

ç\"·$%&/()=?]$ are disallowed characters

I still have the problem, and I don't understand why it is not working

I always see the error message if I write something like: `ABCDEF` (for me it is the right characters) or `ABCDçEF=GHIJ` (incorrect)

In the model I changed RegularExpression like a Custom Attribute. In the property of the model I have:

[CaracteresNoPermitidosAttribute(ErrorMessage="test 123")]
public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

And the Attribute class is:

```
public class CaracteresNoPermitidosAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
public CaracteresNoPermitidosAttribute() : base(GetRegex())
{ }

private static string GetRegex()
{
// I take the data from the table to get the disallowed characters
var lista = (List<Caracterko>) new CaracterkoProxy().ObtenerTodos();

// I transform the list to string
var str = string.Join("", from x in lista where x.Activo select x.Caracter.ToString());

return @"(?![" + str + "])$";
}
}
```

I used the example gave by Tim  as regular expression

Comment: Why is there a `$`? That anchors your regex to the end of the string, _i.e._ only matches those characters at the end of the string. Remove that `$`.

Comment: because it is the collection of characters I have in my table of not allowed characters

Comment: Then put it _inside_ the square brackets: `@"[ç\"·$%&/()=?$]"`.

Comment: With your code, what you are actually saying is "If you don't see any of these characters as the last character of the string input, show the error message." I don't think that's what you actually want to happen.

Comment: I will try to explain again, maybe my english is not the best of the world. If I see any disallowed character (as Tim Ebenezer suggested me), I have to display an error message in the summaryvalidation

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is only looking for one character and then the end of the string. If you only want to allow characters in that set, you should use an expression like - `[ç\"·$%&/()=?]+$`

Since you clarified that you do NOT want these characters in your string, use a negative lookahead:

`(?![ç\"·$%&/()=?])`

Comment: I tested it and I always see the invalid message in all the cases

Comment: Since these are NOT allowed characters, you should be checking for their absence, not their presence. You might want to reflect in your question that these are disallowed characters.